# Adding Swagger to RESTeasy Java Application

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, resteasy

I want to try to add Swagger to my RESTeasy Application. I tried to follow the [Documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-configuration) but i cant reach the Endpoint of Swagger. All i get is an Error 404.

My tech Stack:

- Tomcat 10.0.1
- Java 17

My Goal:

- I want to Access my nice API Documentation under http://localhost:8080/sample/openapi

```
openapi: "3.0.3"
info:
  title: "My API2"
  version: "1.0"
servers:
  - url: "http://localhost:8080/"
paths:
```

openapi.yaml in src/main/resources

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class TimeToolRestApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TimeToolRestApplication.class);

    public TimeToolRestApplication() {
        singletons.add(new HealthController());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

TimeToolRestApplication.java

```
@Path("/v1")
public class HealthController {

    @GET
    @Path("/health")
    public Response healthcheck() {
        return Response.ok().entity(true).build();
    }
}
```

HealthController.java

```
            <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <resteasy.version>6.2.4.Final</resteasy.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-core</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

pom.xml

I tried following the [Documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started) of Swagger. With and without the initializer. But nothing seemed to work

Comment: Old Swagger problem. Start with defaults, no custom URL. Did you raise Spring/Swagger log level to see if initialized? Add spring-boot-actuator to get all endpoints.

Comment: Its not a Spring project. Its a plain simple Java Maven Project with RESTeasy

Comment: You need to use the -jakarta versions of the Swagger dependencies.

Comment: I swapped to the jakarta dependencies but its sadly still not working. I get the Error 404 from tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i fixed it now. I needed to do the following things:

In my Application class:

```
    classes.add(OpenApiResource.class);
    classes.add(AcceptHeaderOpenApiResource.class);
```

I needed to add those.
I also deleted my openapi.yaml and instead used the initializer dependency. As mentioned above and kindly pointed out by @James R. Perkins i switched to the -jakarta dependencies.